What are some good ancient commentaries/writings on the Book of Sirach?
I am planning on leading a Bible Study and want to try and provide some commentary by people such as Augustine, St John Chrysostom, etc. I've tried looking around and found it very difficult to find anything and it seems a lot of the references are implicit rather than explicit from my searching. I found Augustine's "On Grace and Free Will" which has some good references but I'd like to find more if possible.

The catena bible is a good, free jumping off point. I just looked quickly through chapter one, and it contains some implicit references, as well as some sermons on the passages themselves. Another good source would be the Navarre Bible. There is a volume on the Wisdom Literature containing Sirach. I've found that local parish libraries often have at least one or two Navarre volumes on hand, and you could also check your local secular library, and even if they don't have it in their system, they can probably get it to you on Inter Library Loan if you speak to a librarian about it. Or, if you have $50 to splurge, just order your own copy. Lastly, the Ignatius Catholic Study Bible should be on every Catholic's shelf. You could get just the Old Testament volume, but as they recently released both Old and New together, I'd recommend getting that volume to have for any future Bible studies.

Here are some references ...
You should attempt to search for  "ecclesiasticus" which is the alternative title of the Wisdom of Sirach.
During the early church, it was like an ancient version of "12 rules for life" it was a philosopher's advice on pursuing the proper good life. A devotional read among younger disciples, but not equal to the canonical books. (Although it is included within the Orthodox Bible!)

The Father WIlliam Most Collection - This is modern.
An article about John Chrysostom's use of the Book of Sirach in homilies - This is modern about a Church Father... might have something inside.

The following are only references to it... not really what you are looking for.

Ante-Nicene Fathers Volume 2, page ~226 will have St Clement of Alexandria.
Ante-Nicene Fathers, Volume 5, page ~366 will have the Epistles of Cyprian
Ante-Nicene Fathers, Volume 5, page ~547 will have the Treatises of Cyprian
Ante-Nicene Fathers, Volume 8, page ~636 will have the "Twelve Patriarchs, Excerpts and Epistles, The Clementina, Apocryphal Gospels and Acts, Syriac Documents"

... I could list dozens of these. But they are only short references to the text.

Consider catholiccrossreference for more references...

